# Count method references, because of dex file limitation

Tags: android

I want to know the count of method references in my app. Somone can point me to a fitting profile software ? Or is ther maybe some other solution for this ?

Comment: If you use eclipse, put the cursor on the method definition and press `ctl shift g`

Comment: then i get the reference count for this one method ? (i prefer intellij)

Comment: A small search gave me the following shortcut for Intellj: `Ctl Alt F7`.

Comment: thanks for your effort, but i know this shortcut allready. I want to find all method references for all methods in the project. i'm on a mac btw ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but we've recently released a Gradle plugin that will tell you how many method references are in your .apk after every build; it's at https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin.

If you already have an APK and just want to know how many method references are in it, you can find out on the command line (assuming you are using Mac OS X or a UNIX-like).  Unzip your APK and run the following shell command:

```
cat classes.dex | head -c 92 | tail -c 4 | hexdump -e '1/4 "%d\n"'
```

The number of references is part of the dex file header; this pipeline reads the four-byte count at offset 0x5C and prints it as a decimal number.